# How to find the sum of values inside nested arrays and push to new array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

The problem is on leetcode.com, and is # 1672: "Richest Customer Wealth"

Problem text:

> "You are given an m x n integer grid accounts where accounts[i][j] is the amount of money the i​​​​​​​​​​​th​​​​ customer has in the j​​​​​​​​​​​th​​​​ bank. Return the wealth that the richest customer has.
>
> A customer's wealth is the amount of money they have in all their bank accounts. The richest customer is the customer that has the maximum wealth.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: accounts = `[[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]`
> Output: 6
> Explanation:
> 1st customer has wealth = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
> 2nd customer has wealth = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6
> Both customers are considered the richest with a wealth of 6 each, so return 6."*

I'm trying to take the numbers inside of a nested array and push them through to a new array. Once I am able to accomplish this, I can use the sort and slice method on the new array to return the highest value of the new array, but I can't seem to get the nested arrays to add up correctly.

**Example 1:** `[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]` is expected to return `[3, 7, 11]`, which I would sort / splice to return 11, but the new array only returns `[3]`.

**Example 2:** `[[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]` expected to return `[6, 6]`, but only returns `[6]`.

I believe the issue is that the for loop is not iterating through the entire array for some reason, and is only returning the value of the first nested array.

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} accounts
 * @return {number}
 */
const maximumWealth = (accounts) => {
    let total = 0;
    let totalArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < accounts.length; ++i) {
        if (Array.isArray(accounts[i])) {
            total += maximumWealth(accounts[i]);
            totalArr.push(total);
            console.log(totalArr);
        } else {
            total += accounts[i];
        }
    }
    return total;
};
```

When printing `totalArr` to the console from `console.log(totalArr);` it is only returning the value of the first nested array.

Comment: There's no need to sort to get the maximum element. Use `Math.max(...array)`

Comment: More simply, don't we want the largest sum of all of the subarray sums?  You can get the sum by `let sum = arr => arr.reduce((a, el) => a+el, 0))`.  You can get the max (as others have suggested) with `Math.max(...accounts.map(sum))`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback--I'm still really new to this so I make some stupid mistakes that are beneath the pros haha

Answer (score 1):

You're not summing each nested array. Use this to get the total of each account. Get the maximum of the result after calling this.

```js
function sumArrays(accounts) {
    return accounts.map(account => {
        let total = 0;
        account.forEach(val => total += val);
        return total;
    });
}

console.log(sumArrays([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]));
console.log(sumArrays([[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]));
```

To get the maximum, combine that with a call to `Math.max()`.

```js
    function sumArrays(accounts) {
        return accounts.map(account => {
            let total = 0;
            account.forEach(val => total += val);
            return total;
        });
    }
    
    function maximumWealth(accounts) {
      let totals = sumArrays(accounts);
      return Math.max(...totals);
    }

    console.log(maximumWealth([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]));
    console.log(maximumWealth([[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]));
```

Comment: Thanks! This is producing the totals of the nested arrays (accounts), but for some reason I can't seem to get them to push to a new array. It just returns multiple single value arrays based on the totals of the accounts, but won't push them to a single array.

Comment: It's returning the array of totals, you don't need to push to anything.

Comment: You said you wanted to get the result `[3, 7, 11]` in the first example, that's what this returns.

Comment: You're right! I made a stupid syntax error and realized when I copy pasted your code. It does work when I use the console.log like you do but for some reason it's throwing a type error in leetcodes console: TypeError: account.forEach is not a function

Comment: Are you sure it's passing the MxN array to `sumArrays`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use this when getting the maximum wealth.

Comment: When I test it with console.log it does not appear that it is--thank you for the suggestion!

If I can find a way to get the MxN array to pass to sumArrays I should be able to get this working--much appreciated!!!

Comment: Thank you again--the update and explanation is very helpful to a newbie like me, that got it working fully!

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your initial array to [reduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) arrays of the totals and then use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to find out the max amount.

```js
const addNumbersInArray = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value)
}

const maximumWealth = (accounts) => {
  const addedNumbers = accounts.map(addNumbersInArray);
  return Math.max(...addedNumbers);
};

console.log({
  '[[6,2,3], [3,2,4]]': maximumWealth([[6,2,3], [3,2,4]])
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely is a better solution than what I was trying, and easier to understand. I've been trying to understand for loops better so that's why I was trying a more complicated approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for a function like this, especially if your goal was to use recursion; no need of local variables as they are re-initialized at every call:

```js
const maximumWealth = (accounts) => {
    if( accounts.length && Array.isArray(accounts[0]) ) {
        return accounts.map(maximumWealth);
    } else if( accounts.length ) {
        return accounts.pop() + maximumWealth(accounts);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

console.log( maximumWealth([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]) );
console.log( maximumWealth([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]) );
```

Then you could sort the result as you had planned and `pop` or `shift` the max result. You could also use the `max` method as suggested by @Barmar (see comments & answer):

- **SORTING**

```js
const maximumWealth = (accounts) => {
    if( accounts.length && Array.isArray(accounts[0]) ) {
        return accounts.map(maximumWealth);
    } else if( accounts.length ) {
        return accounts.pop() + maximumWealth(accounts);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

console.log( maximumWealth([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]).sort((a,b) => a - b).pop() );
console.log( maximumWealth([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]).sort((a,b) => a - b).pop() );
```

- **`Math.max()`**

```js
const maximumWealth = (accounts) => {
    if( accounts.length && Array.isArray(accounts[0]) ) {
        return accounts.map(maximumWealth);
    } else if( accounts.length ) {
        return accounts.pop() + maximumWealth(accounts);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

console.log( Math.max( ...maximumWealth([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]) ) );
console.log( Math.max( ...maximumWealth([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]) ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!! The console.logs return the correct results but when I try putting in accounts instead of the arrays it doesn't wanna work.

I'm trying to use something like: 

    return maximumWealth(accounts).sort((a,b) => a - b).pop(); 

or returning the Math.max approach but it keeps throwing an error

Comment: @elborracho420 I think you're sorting the wrong elements; you're trying to sort a subset of the *row* array elements instead of sorting the array of the sum of the *rows*. At any one time `maximumWealth` only has the elements of a single *row*; so perhaps its name is misleading. Maybe a better name would be `sumRow`.